# Ktor getting 403 forbidden error when requesting api using cloudflare

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I started a new Android project.This time I decided to use Ktor instead of Retrofit as a network client.The api uses CloudFlare.When I send a request to the api, I get a 403 Forbidden Error.If I use Retrofit, this problem does not occur.I think the problem is in the common headers that Ktor sends, but I cannot delete the headers no matter what I do.How can I solve this problem? I don’t want to use Retrofit.

Comment: "I cannot delete headers" - retrofit does not send empty headers as default either. You have to compare them yourself, pinpoint the offending one and change its value. You have not posted much details here but ill just shoot a guess that it is `User-Agent`, a lot of end points aggressively filter by it.

Comment: 1) Log the payload before sending
2) Compare both of them side by side

Else add more details to the above problem:- 
There is a possibility of failing authorisation where possibly retrofit sends while ktor is not configured to send or is sending incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `Accept-Charset: UTF-8` header which is added by Ktor by default. As a workaround, you can remove that header using a plugin:

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(createClientPlugin("fix") {
        on(Send) { request ->
            request.headers.remove("Accept-Charset")
            this.proceed(request)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. I had previously tried to remove the header within the defaultRequest block and the HttpRequestBuilder block, but it just wouldn't delete. Your method did the trick.